# PostSharp build error with Appveyor

Tags: c#, postsharp, appveyor

I'm trying to deploy my code to a Build Machine on AppVeyor, and I Found that I need to create a **postsharp.config** file with my license details to build, but I'm having the following error:

> C:\projects\webapibase\packages\PostSharp.5.0.41\build\PostSharp.targets(314,5):
>   error PS0260: License error. The license
>   xxx is not allowed to be loaded from
>   C:\projects\webapibase\Service\postsharp.config.
>   [C:\projects\webapibase\Service\Service.csproj]
>   C:\projects\webapibase\packages\PostSharp.5.0.41\build\PostSharp.targets(314,5):
>   error PS0242: License error. No valid license key has been installed.
>   Please visit https://www.postsharp.net/purchase to acquire a license
>   of PostSharp. To register a license key, use PostSharp Essentials or
>   start the evaluation period, execute the program

I have created the postsharp.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
  <License Value="xxxx" />
</Project>
```

Ps. The same project in VSTS build normally (without the file), probably PostSharp detects a build machine and ignore the license check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, the solution is add the RegKey before Build:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SharpCrafters\PostSharp 3" /v LicenseKey /t REG_SZ /d <your_license>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solution still works for PostSharp: https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/934-postsharp-free-licences-do-not-work-on-the-new-environment#comment_35059947

Comment: Unfortunately don’t work. It’s what I described about creating the .config file :/ thanks for the helo